# Standalone Glassfish fails to start with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: glassfish

I've unzipped Glassfish 3.1.2.2 from a zip file on a Debian machine running Java 1.6.0_10. When I try to start Glassfish it fails with a ClassNotFoundException.

```
java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file /u/seqprodbio/bin/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/endorsed/._webservices-api-osgi.jar
```

Machine Info

```
$ uname -a
Linux platinum 3.2.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1~bpo60+1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ hostname
platinum
$ domainname
(none)
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
10.0.0.207  platinum.company.com    platinum
```

Java Info

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_10-b33)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0-b15, mixed mode)
```

Full Log

```
$ ./asadmin start-domain --verbose domain1
27-Sep-2013 4:51:02 PM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: JVM invocation command line:
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:PermSize=64m
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Xmx512m
-javaagent:/u/seqprodbio/bin/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-client
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=/u/seqprodbio/bin/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/u/seqprodbio/bin/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Djava.security.policy=/u/seqprodbio/bin/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/server.policy
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=/u/seqprodbio/bin/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/u/seqprodbio/bin/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/endorsed:/u/seqprodbio/bin/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/endorsed
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=/u/seqprodbio/bin/glassfish3/glassfish
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Djava.ext.dirs=/cr/local/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_10/lib/ext:/cr/local/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_10/jre/lib/ext:/u/seqprodbio/bin/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/u/seqprodbio/bin/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/u/seqprodbio/bin/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/login.conf
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
27-Sep-2013 4:51:02 PM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: Successfully launched in 15 msec.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file /u/seqprodbio/bin/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/endorsed/._webservices-api-osgi.jar
Command start-domain failed.
The DAS was stopped.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the directory containing that JAR to your java CLASSPATH.

The CLASSPATH is an environment variable that tells the system where to look for java classes. For details on how to set it go [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Also, check if your JAVA_HOME variable is set.